# RadDropDownTree Version of DropDownList.Items.Clear()

Tags: c#, telerik

I have multiple sqldatasources which are fed to the RadDropDownTree. Before it was a Dropdownlist and now changed it to a RadDropDownTree

What is the way to clear the items when another dropdownlist is changed

I before had DropDownListName.Items.Clear()  what is the equivlant code for this in RadDropDownTree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RadDropDownTree` control has a property called `Entries` which returns a 
`EntryCollection` object, where you will be able to call `Clear()` method to clear the entries. 
Also you can take a look at another property called `EmbeddedTree` which returns a `RadTreeView` object, where you can then access and manipulate its `Nodes`.

```
RadDropDownTree1.Entries.Clear();
RadDropDownTree1.EmbeddedTree.Nodes.Clear();
```